# Proving BinPacking is NP-complete given Partition problem is NP-hard

Tags: computer-science, np-complete

I'm trying to prove that the BinPacking problem is NP hard granted the partition problem *is NP hard*. If I have E a set of positive integers, can I split it into two subsets such that the sums of the integers in both subsets are equal?

The polynomial reduction I found would be the following:

- My objects O are defined as what's in E (the weight of each object is the integer value and |E| is the number of objects)
- Number of bags = 2
- Capacity of each bag is half of the sum of everything in E

Is this wrong because my polynomial reduction only reduces to BinPacking with **2 bags** whose **capacity are the same**?

I’m skeptic because if I carry out this proof, and I find an algorithm in polynomial time for the partition problem I will only have proof that BinPacking with 2 bags whose capacity are the same is solvable in a polynomial time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pleasantly surprising that you got a simple reduction from the partition problem to the BinPacking problem. Instead of being skeptic, you are supposed to celebrate your elegant proof.

Here is a little lemma for this occasion.

Let us represent [a decision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem#Definition) by $(I, Y)$, where $I$ is an infinite set of inputs and $Y\subseteq I$ is the subset of inputs for which the answer is YES.

**(All is at least as hard as a part)** Lemma: Let $I^-\subseteq I$. If $(I^-, Y\cap I^-)$ is NP-hard, so is $(I,Y)$.
Proof: Obvious. (Please make sure you can prove it rigorously.)

Since you have proved the partial BinPacking problem, which is with 2 bags whose capacity are the same is NP-hard, so is the whole BinPacking problem.

---

If we only deduce in term of NP-hardness, a polynomial-time algorithm for the partition problem would imply "that BinPacking with 2 bags whose capacity are the same is solvable in a polynomial time" only. It does not imply the existence of a polynomial-time algorithm for the (whole) BinPacking problem.

However, since the partition problem is NP-complete and (the decision version of) the BinPacking problem is a NP-problem, a polynomial-time algorithm for the partition problem will immediately gives a polynomial-time algorithm for the BinPacking problem once we integrate with a polynomial-time reduction of the BinPacking problem to the partition problem.

---

What you see here is a very general phenomenon.

In fact, people have been researching intensively, for an NP-hard problem $(I,Y)$, how much smaller $I^-$ can be so that $(I^-, Y\cap I^-)$ remains NP-hard. A very small such $I'$ will illustrate where the NP-hardness of $(I, Y)$ comes from. Here we can say that the NP-hardness of BinPacking problem is already present in the much smaller case of two bags with equal capacity.

When $I^-$ becomes smaller enough, it may happen that it is "hard" to compute the YES/NO answer to most large elements of $I^-$. We could then say $I^-$ are  hard instances of $I$. You can take a look at [Hard instances and phase-transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Hard_instances_and_phase-transition).

Comment: While it is very clear to me why "All is at least as hard as a part", I'm having trouble understanding why "a polynomial-time algorithm for the partition problem will immediately gives a polynomial-time algorithm for the BinPacking problem"

Comment: Is this the result of a theorem I might have forgotten? "since the partition problem is NP-complete and (the decision version of) the BinPacking problem is a NP-problem, a polynomial-time algorithm for the partition problem will immediately gives a polynomial-time algorithm for the BinPacking problem once we integrate with a polynomial-time reduction of the BinPacking problem to the partition problem.". Are we sure there exists a polynomial-time reduction of the BinPacking problem to the partition problem? The reduction I showed doesn't prove this other reduction exists, does it?

Comment: Yes, we are absolutely sure that there exists a polynomial-time reduction of the BinPacking problem to the partition problem. What you have written in the question proves basically the other way around: a polynomial-time reduction of the partition problem to (a part of) the BinPacking problem. However, the partition problem is **NP-complete**. It looks you missed [the definition of NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness#Formal_definition). **Please check what it means.**

Comment: Indeed, I learned that a NP-complete problem was a (decision) problem who was NP and that we could reduce another NP-complete problem to it. Those two definitions don't seem equivalent, there must be a proof that they are, right? I guess that's what I'm missing.

Comment: Please read the part II of [this great post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/18666/91753) on the definition of P, NP, NP-complete and NP-hard. You may want to review [the part I](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/9566/91753) of it as well.

Comment: Oooh, a NP-complete problem is a problem which ALL NP PROBLEMS can be reduced to, which is a polynomial-time reduction of the BinPacking problem to the partition problem exists?!

It must've been hard to prove that the "first" NP Problem was NP complete, right? After that, you "just" need to prove that one NP-complete problem can be reduced to your problem your problem becomes NP-complete?

Comment: You got all correctly. The first NP-complete problem is one of the greatest discoveries in the history of compute science. The existence of an NP-complete problem is also one of the most beautiful theorems.

Comment: Found the first NP-complete problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%E2%80%93Levin_theorem (for other people that might be reading our discussion).
Thanks for your help. Was eye-opening.

Answer (score 0):

It is not wrong, you effectively reduce only some of the BinPacking problem instances.
You will only have an *explicit* solution for BinPacking with 2 bags, this is correct also.